# Objects fall off screen, because stay one behind another[unity]

Tags: 2d, unity

I m learning unity, I placed objects on a scene, camera is looking at them and displays them fine.

but in 3d, I can see they are one behind another, so when i hit play button, they just fall!

Pic:
[image: rrr]

is there any specific button like "align on one level" in unity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you have attached `Rigidbody` or `Rigidbody2D` to them. Just mark as `Kinematic` in Rigidbody's configuration in `Inspector`. By attaching `Rigidbody` or `Rigidbody2D` your body will behave like real world object following all the physics rules. In this case it is falling down probably due to gravity. By marking as `Kinematic` it you defined your behaviour as not to receive any force or gravity but still a physical body.

Comment: yes, I did attach some rigidbody

Comment: but I also put box collider to ground - the thing is, they stand behind another in 3d, i m making 2d game

Comment: mark check on `Is Kinematic`

Comment: So you want to say objects should fall but on ground and the objects are falling on the ground but out of screen? right?

Comment: no, they fall absolutely down , even though now, they are on one z-axis(aka not behind another)

Comment: hmm, strange, i checked true for is_kinematic, and they dont' fall  now.. , but i wanted it to fall to the ground and stay on top of it

Comment: Z-axis doesn't matter in 2D environment except of Camera's Clipping planes. Well, did you attach collider on ground?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33434/discussion-between-hamza-hasan-and-erjan).

Comment: @ERJAN check this out friend :) [Modified Project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lsucitafkpw5od7/erjan_trying.zip?dl=0)